# Is it possible to get the background color of an element that is being set via an external css file?

Tags: javascript, css

I was trying to get the background color of an element using javascript:

**URL:** https://mathemagiker.de/

**Javascript:** document.getElementById('angebot').style.backgroundColor

**Result:** Nothing

However this element has a background color but it is being applied from a css file.

**Question:** How can I get this color with javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('angebot')).backgroundColor
```

Result: `"rgb(102, 185, 191)"` (for the URL that you provided)

The reason why `document.getElementById('angebot').style.backgroundColor` didn't return anything was because the element was styled with CSS and not with the inline `.style`.

`The HTMLElement.style property is used to get as well as set the inline style of an element.`

Comment: awesome, don't even know we can get element's computed styles. Thanks @DrNio :)

Comment: welcome..feel free to accept the answer :) i will update my answer with a bit more information